# Laravel 4 not redirecting guest users to the login page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the default set of filters, including the below:

```
Route::filter('auth', function () {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
});

Route::filter('guest', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```

However, when I debug the application it gets into neither of them. There're no cookies or anything - the user is not logged in and should therefore be redirected to the login page, but this is not happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you calling the filters? like this?

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    return 'You are authorized!';
}));
```

or in a controller?

```
$this->beforeFilter('auth');
```

Comment: Aha. I wasn't calling it explicitly at all - I assumed incorrectly that the filters applied automagically in the same way as routes do.